# Replication stops with GTID_NEXT error after creation/drop of memory table in mysql5.6

Tags: replication, mysql-5.6, upgrade, memory-optimized-tables, gtid

We have recently upgraded to mysql5.6.25 from mysql5.5.x/mysql5.1.x on our mysql-cluster.
Below is a brief snapshot of our architecture.
[image]

Since we have upgraded and enabled gtid-mode we have been intermittently getting slave errors similar to :

***Last_SQL_Error: Error 'When @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT is set to a GTID, you must explicitly set it to a different value after a COMMIT or ROLLBACK. Please check GTID_NEXT variable manual page for detailed explanation. Current @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT is 'd7e8990d-3a9e-11e5-8bc7-22000aa63d47:1466'.' on query. Default database: 'adplatform'. Query: 'create table X_new like X'***

Our observations are as below..

- These slave errors are resolved simply by restarting the slave.
- Such errors are always with Create/Drop of tables which have Memory Storage Engine.
- Errors on Complete-Slave(B) show up continuously at a fixed minute (39th) of the hour and have been repeating since we have upgraded, almost a week.
- Errors on Complete-Slave as well as Partial slave are observed whenever its master is restarted.
- Cluster-1 and Cluster-2 have centos machines and Cluster-3 have ubuntu-machines. Slaves on centos machines also fail with the same error whenever its master(C/D) is restarted, but slave on ubuntu machines do not fail!!.

We have temporarily been able to live with this issue by setting up an action-script on our monitoring system which fires on slave error alert on any machine.

A look into gtid_next section in replication-options doc of mysql tells following

> Prior to MySQL 5.6.20, when GTIDs were enabled but gtid_next was not
>   AUTOMATIC, DROP TABLE did not work correctly when used on a
>   combination of nontemporary tables with temporary tables, or of
>   temporary tables using transactional storage engines with temporary
>   tables using nontransactional storage engines. In MySQL 5.6.20 and
>   later, DROP TABLE or DROP TEMPORARY TABLE fails with an explicit error
>   when used with either of these combinations of tables. (Bug #17620053)

This seems related to my issue but still doesn't not explain my scenario.
Any hints/direction to solve the issue would be greatly appreciated...

**EDIT :** 
I managed to find a similar recently reported bug in mysql(#77729), description of which is as follows :

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77729

> When you have table with Engine MEMORY working on replication master,
>   mysqld injects "DELETE" statement in binary logs on first access query
>   to this table. This insures consistency of data on replicating slaves.
>
> If replication is GTID ROW based, this inserted "DELETE" breaks
>   replication.  Logged event is in STATEMENT format and do not generate
>   correct SET GTID_NEXT statements in binary log.

Unfortunately, the status of this bug is marked as `Can't Repeat`...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem that generated the same error. On a master instance I dropped a database.

On a slave there was a file left over `<tablename>.exp` (I forget what purpose this serves).

The slave replication died with

> last_Error: Error 'DROP DATABASE failed; some tables may have been
> dropped but the database directory remains. The GTID has not been
> added to GTID_EXECUTED and the statement was not written to the binary
> log. Fix this as follows: (1) remove all files from the database
> directory ./db_to_drop/; (2) SET
> GTID_NEXT='c62b6474-84e6-11e8-bf49-00164ef9ea6c:73066506'; (3) DROP
> DATABASE `db_to_drop`.' on query. Default database: 'db_to_drop'.
> Query: 'drop database db_to_drop'

I removed the file, ran the `SET` and restarted replication:

> SET GTID_NEXT='c62b6474-84e6-11e8-bf49-00164ef9ea6c:73066506';
> start slave; ERROR 1837 (HY000): When @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT is set to a
> GTID, you must explicitly set it to a different value after a COMMIT
> or ROLLBACK. Please check GTID_NEXT variable manual page for detailed
> explanation. Current @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT is
> 'c62b6474-84e6-11e8-bf49-00164ef9ea6c:73066506'.

And this, from following the suggestion. Since it's only a development cluster, I wasn't worried about losing it entirely, so I punted and tried setting it to the next GTID.

`SET GTID_NEXT='c62b6474-84e6-11e8-bf49-00164ef9ea6c:73066507';`

(i.e. + 1). Restarted replication and things got back to normal.